# SQL Server : How to get rownumber for each common set of values?

Tags: sql-server-2005

Say my table is like this...

```
`
Tenancy Number    Tenant Number    Tenant
1                   1               John
1                   2               Jane
1                   3               Pete
2                   56              Fred
2                   78              Jackie
```

How can I select the rownumber based on grouping by the tenany number? So far I can get the row number in, but I can't figure a way to "reset" that upon next tenancy number.

I would like to achieve the following results

```
MYROWNUM         Tenancy Number    Tenant Number        Tenant
    1                1                   1               John
    2                1                   2               Jane
    3                1                   3               Pete
    1                2                   56              Fred
    2                2                   78              Jackie
```

Sorry if I haven't explained this too well!

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Tenancy Number]
                          ORDER BY [Tenant Number]
                         ) AS myrownum
       ,[Tenancy Number]
       ,[Tenant Number]
       ,Tenant
from <table>
```

Comment: Thanks, the PARTITION BY fixed my issue ;)

Comment: Perfect answer, it would be nice to have also an explanation related to the difference of using ORDER BY and PARTITION BY inside the function ROW_NUMBER()

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [row_number()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms186734.aspx) function for this.

Example:

```
 SELECT 
    SalesOrderID, OrderDate, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderDate) AS 'RowNumber'
 FROM 
    Sales.SalesOrderHeader
```

HTH

Comment: actually, that doesn't take into account that the "MYROWNUM" should start at 1 for each new "Tenancy Number". You're missing a "PARTIION BY" clause in your `row_number() OVER....` function call

Comment: This got me half way there, just needed the PARTITION BY. ;)

Comment: Without PARTITION BY this solution doesn't work as expected

Answer (score 3):

Use the Row_Number() function:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (TenancyNbr smallint, TenantNbr smallint, Tenant varchar(10))
INSERT INTO @t
SELECT 1,1,'Jack'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,2,'Janet'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,3, 'Chrissy'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,56, 'Mr. Roper'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,78, 'Mrs. Roper'


SELECT MyRowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TenancyNbr ORDER BY TenantNbr),
    TenancyNbr, TenantNbr, Tenant
FROM @t
```